# I have 2x 3-Way leviton switches in one dual gang can i Merge those and have the option to turn on the lights on 3 spots?

Tags: multiway-switch

So I knocked down a wall on the foyer of the house to expand a living area, on the foyer was 1 spotlight that was connected to a 3 way switch (1 in the foyer next to the door, 1 in the Livingroom) on that Livingroom box was a second 3 way Switch powering the Livingroom pocket lights, the second switch for this one is located next to the stairs, when the Handy man that knocked the wall connected the lights from the Livingroom to the Foyer circuit so now the 3 way switch for the Livingroom does nothing I would like to merge the "foyer and Livingroom" 3 ways that are in the same box to have 3 switches that can power on the same set of lights.

let me know if you understand and if its possible without any major work.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: This is the BOX i would like to merge the Right one is the one currently working the one on the Left is doing nothing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/16AJrWvR7qFijU0Z602aukC4tLbWDx1rK/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zte67_lEldnTerzD-6ZJVy8R1J3KYR13/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can we have photos of the insides of the other switch boxes as well please?

Comment: This is the front door switchbox, again the right one is the one managing the lights, Left one is another light no issues there:  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z8k6m-oMibHj-1UTeP_dF9YJ-912wc-z/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZiqOcLt0cTUamjEZEqYTxVnzBChBqfKI/view?usp=sharing
this is the one on the stairs, the one on the right was the livingroom switch doing nothing now.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CtLJbYnDnBUwnHw04AkrVvdGc2DfYZgs/view?usp=sharing,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dRk8sfBOlJUIb0lrT45um9-MxFwXdlXX/view?usp=sharing